# How can I fix the formatting on these graphs?

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, chart.js

I am using the chart.js library to generate these graphs. I cannot get the title of the doughnut chart to stack over the actual chart or the legend of the doughnut chart to be lowered a little, and the label of the grouped bar chart is cut off. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxCgn.png)

Here is my code for both the charts: (This is in a Django template)

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mb-4">
     <div class="col-span-0 w-full rounded-xl p-4" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
          <canvas id="chart_revenue"></canvas>
     </div>
     <script>
          let ctx_revenue = document.getElementById("chart_revenue").getContext("2d");
          let chart_revenue = new Chart(ctx_revenue, {
               type: "doughnut",
               data: {
                    labels: [
                         {% for project in all_projects %}
                              ['{{project.name}}', '{{project.client.name}}'],
                         {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    datasets: [{
                         label: "Revenue",
                         data: [
                              {% for project in all_projects %}
                                   {{project.total_cost}},
                              {% endfor %}
                         ],
                         hoverOffset: 4
                    }]
               },
               options: {
                    animation: {
                         animateRotate: true,
                         animateScale: true,
                         duration: 1000,
                         easing: "easeOutQuart"
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    plugins: {
                         title: {
                         display: true,
                         text: ["Revenue Distribution", "Total Revenue: ${{total_revenue}}",
                                   "Total Clients: {{total_clients}}"],
                         align: 'center',
                         padding: {
                              top: 0,
                              bottom: 20
                         },
                         font: {
                              size: 18,
                              weight: "bold"
                         }
                     },
                     legend: {
                          display: true,
                          position: "right",
                          labels: {
                               font: {
                                    size: 14
                               }
                           }
                     },
               }
               }
          });
     </script>
     <div class="col-span-1 w-full rounded-xl p-4" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
           <canvas id="chart_project"></canvas>
     </div>
     <script>
           let ctx_project = document.getElementById("chart_project").getContext("2d");
           let chart_project = new Chart(ctx_project, {
                type: "bar",
                data: {
                    labels: [
                        {% for fiscal_year in fiscal_years %}
                            '{{fiscal_year.name}}',
                        {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Projects",
                            data: [
                                {% for num_projects in num_projects_by_fiscal_year %}
                                    {{num_projects}},
                                {% endfor %}
                             ],
                             hoverOffset: 4
                        },
                        {
                             label: "Pending Project Requests",
                             data:[
                                 {% for num_pending_project_requests in 
                                      num_pending_project_requests_by_fiscal_year %}
                                      {{num_pending_project_requests}},
                                 {% endfor %}
                             ],
                             hoverOffset: 4
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    animation: {
                        animateRotate: true,
                        animateScale: true,
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: "easeOutQuart"
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: true,
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            Min: 0,
                            suggestedMax: 10
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: ["Project Count", "Total Projects: {{total_projects}}", 
                            "Total Project Requests: {{total_project_requests}}", 
                            "Total Pending Projects Requests: 
                                  {{total_pending_project_requests}}"],
                            align: 'center',
                            padding: {
                                top: 10,
                                bottom: 30
                        },
                        font: {
                            size: 18,
                            weight: "bold"
                        }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                            position: "right",
                            labels: {
                                font: {
                                size: 14
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }
                });      
            </script>
        </div>
```

I have tried changing the padding and the position of the titles/legends but none of that has worked. Most of the time there is no change.

Comment: When it comes to centering the chart title - it's already centered, it's just that your legend is on the right-hand side of it, so the title's position looks a bit off. You would need to use a custom HTML / CSS / JS for this (possibly a callback for the title, which would always center it over the chart, regardless of the legend's position). As for the cutoff of the second graph's legend - you can't wrap long lines natively, but you can organize them like an array, instead of a string: `label: ["Pending", "Projects Requests"]` instead of `label: "Pending Projects Requests"`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, thanks for the suggestino about the second graph! It worked for the most part. For the first graph, how would I use a callback function here? I just learned what they are but I don't really get how that helps me position the title.

Comment: Perhaps [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/32oc1bej/). I've hardcoded the data for the sake of the fiddle. The titles are in the code, but they're not displayed within the canvas - they're used as the sources for the doughnut and bar charts, respectively. This gives you more options to manipulate their position, but it won't let you save the titles as parts of the chart (since they're not visible within the canvas).

Comment: @FiddlingAway I actually encountered another problem I don't know if you have any ideas on what is going on. I am destroying the charts I rendered and then redrawing them. However, for the doughnut chart when I redraw it the chart grows bigger and the legend cuts off. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: My advice is to open another question, since it's a different problem.